# JQuery: Populate secondary select options using php based on primary selected option

Tags: jquery, select, html-select

What I am trying to do is to **populate the secondary select options** using php and a database based on the users **primary input** using JQuery. If dogs is selected, populate dog breeds, cats - cat breeds and so on.

**Primary Input**

```
<select id="animal" name="animal">
    <option value="dogs" <?php if ($animaltype == 'dogs') echo 'selected'; ?>>Dogs</option>
    <option value="cats" <?php if ($animaltype == 'cats') echo 'selected'; ?>>Cats</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
    $('select#animal').change(function() {
       var animal = $("select option:selected").attr('value');
       $('select#breed').load(animal);
       alert(animal);
    })
```

I added the alert(animal) to make sure it's pasing the right value which it does, dogs, cats, horses ... this is to target the database table name. What I'm trying to achieve is to change the mysql query to take that value. For example, `"SELECT breed FROM animal"` animal being what jquery is returning.

```
<select id="breed" name="breed">
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT breed, url FROM {$animaltype}";
                $results = mysql_query($query);             

                while($breed = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                    echo '<option value="'. $breed['url'] .'">'. $breed['breed'] .'</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
```

I'm guessing I need a $.post, in the jquery script, to post the request to that php page, and then assign the value to the $animaltype in the select query?  Totally new to jquery/php so go easy on me ;) Hope I've explained enough to understand. THANKS!

Comment: What you need is an `ajax` and why would you  use `load` here??

Comment: I was sort of following a tutorial that did something similar and thought that was the correct way to do it. I am new to this hah. I'm guessing I need to post the value of **var animal** to the sql query, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it!?

Comment: http://alistapart.com/d/complexdynamiclists/dynamicselect.html This is the sort of thing I'm trying to do, using JQuery so that it populates on the fly, without having to reload the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select#animal').change(function() {
       var animal = $("select option:selected").attr('value');
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourpage.php",
        data: { animal: animal  }
    });
    });

     var updateAnimal = function(url, breed){
        //use url and breed variables here however you want, e.g
    $('.someselectbox').append('<option value="'+url+'">'+breed+'</option>');
}

</script>

And then in your php


<?php
if(isset($_POST['animal']))
{
    $animal = $_POST['animal'];


    $query = "SELECT breed, url FROM $animal}";
    $results = mysql_query($query);             

    while($breed = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        echo echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                 updateAnimal('.$breed['url'].', '.$breed['breed'].');
              </script>';

    }
}
?>
```

Edited with a better understanding of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1
You are render your page and must via php fill initial options and default value for SELECT with id="animal"  and  SELECT with id="breed". This part you perform via PHP

Part 2
The user choose option in SELECT with id="animal"  and you must perform AJAX request (by the way you can use .get instead .post) to get JSON array of data for SELECT with id="breed". This part you perform via JQuery.

Part 3 
Make query to database and do output of JSON array. This part you perform via PHP

Part 4
The callback function of your AJAX request receive response from server and render options for SELECT with id="breed" and choose default option. This part you perform via JQuery.